# Цикл и функция cin.get()

Tags: c++, cin

Пишу программу,где каждую секунду пользователь должен вводить определенный символ в консоль.Пользуюсь для этого функцией `cin.get(ch)`.Проблема в том,что она принимает и Enter за символ тоже и кладет его в буфер входного потока,поэтому когда через секунду снова вызывается `cin.get(ch)` программа сама туда вводит символ `'\n'`,не дожидаясь пользователя.Как с этим бороться?Конечно,можно перед следующим вызовом `cin.get(ch)` сначала вызвать "холостую" `cin.get()`,которая не записывает никакого значения в переменную,дабы очистить буфер потока,но это больше похоже на какой-то костыль...Да и этот трюк уже не сработает,если в буфере окажется вдруг больше одного символа.
И еще,есть какие нибудь функции,которые считывают по одному символу,не дожидаясь,пока пользователь нажмет Enter?Желательно из стандартных библиотек С++.

Comment: А может найти способ ввода без enter'а?

Comment: @Qwertiy в библиотеке `conio.h` есть функция `_getch();`,которая не требует ввода Enter,но и она вставляет нолик в буфер после того,как вводишь символ :) В свое время,дабы решить эту проблему,я написал функцию с использованием цикла `while`,которая разгружает входной буфер,пока не получит Enter,но смысла описывать ее здесь не вижу,ибо там все равно придется некоторые вещи переписывать под конкретную задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант
`if (ch == '\r') сh = getch();`
или использовать 
`cin.ignore();`

Comment: `(ch == '\r')`,но ведь enter интерпретируется как linefeed,а не cr..Или я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: @escape, да, должно быть `\n`